# How to access js files in orangehrm-3.1.1 using symfony 1.4

Tags: symfony-1.4, orangehrm

I build a form under Admin Tab in orangehrm-3.1.1 and used commands symfony doctrine:build -model and forms for displaying the form.I created js files for that form.when I want to save form data in database,It was not saving,It was not accessing js file.should I have to run any command for that?Any suggestion would be of great help for mme

Answer (score 1):

Where do you put your js files?

If it's under plugin's `web/js` folder, try this command `php symfony orangehrm:publish-assets`

and in your template add this code:

`use_javascript(plugin_web_path('[YOUR_PLUGIN_NAME]', 'js/[YOUR_JS_FILE]'));`

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked file permission of js file folder?

Comment: How to check/place permissions for js folder?

Comment: If you are in linux system like ubuntu You can check it by going to the files root directory using cd/ and then ls -la to see its ownership. For other OS try google

Answer (score 0):

If it is under symfony/web/js then just use

```
use_javascript(plugin_web_path('', 'js/yourjsfile.js'));
```